# Dynamic Grunt involving n subdirectories

Tags: javascript, git, gruntjs

I have a folder layout such that:

```
/ 
-- css/
-- js/
-- apps/
-- -- myFirstApp/
-- -- mySecondApp/
-- -- ...
```

Each of these are git submodules, and have a corresponding Gruntfile, package.json, etc. What I want to do is the same sequence of commands, but differ depending on the respective package.json.

My command list is this:

```
npm install
grunt dist
copy app/css/[fileName].css (from package.json) to css/
copy app/js/[fileName].js to js/
copy app/js/[fileName].html to /
```

Is there a plugin or something I'm overlooking that I can use with grunt to do this? I don't want to do it statically if at all possible -- I'd like to only have to update the submodule list for this to work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is coming in from the `package.json` of each submodule... is it the `[fileName]`? The entire directory? I don't know of anything that would read a submodule's `package.json` file for the parent's Grunt task, but you can [write your own tasks](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks) pretty easily which can read the file system (using Node) and copy/write files.

Comment: package.json has an attribute named `fileName` which dictates the name of the resulting js/css/html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any pre-built Grunt task that will do this for you, but writing the task isn't so difficult. You'll need to pull in the Node `fs` module to deal with the filesystem and obviously there will be some other things to do... here's a general structure for it with some code and some `TODO`'s:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    path = require("path");

module.exports = function ( grunt ) {
  grunt.initConfig({

    ... // all of your other Grunt config

    // options for our new task
    copymodulefiles: {
      all: {
        rootDir: "apps/"
      }
    }

  });

  // Here's our custom task definition
  grunt.registerMultiTask("copymodulefiles", "Copies files from sub-projects", function() {
    var done = this.async(), // tell Grunt this is an async task
        root = grunt.config(this.name + "." + this.target + ".rootDir"),
        modules = fs.readdirSync(root);

    modules.forEach(function(dirName) {
      var pkg = fs.readFileSync(root + dirName + path.sep + "package.json", "utf8");
          pkgJson = JSON.parse(pkg);

      // TODO: find what you need in the pkgJson variable
      //       copy files from wherever to wherever

      // You can write a file like so:
      fs.writeFile(theFilenameToWrite, "Contents of the new file", function (err) {
        // (check for errors!)

        // log it?
        grunt.log.ok("file written!");
      });

    });

    // Determine when all are complete and call "done()" to tell Grunt everything's complete
    // call Grunt's "done" method to signal task completion
    done();

  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) i found it perfect and did similar tasks like what you are trying to do.

Have a look at my **Gruntfile.js** configuration what i have written to run shell commands:

```
shell: {
        multiple: {
            command: ['bower install',
                      'mv bower_components/** public/',
                  'rm -rf bower_components'
                  ].join('&&')
        }
    }
```

So here i am  running **bower**, then i am copying its components to public folder and after that i am deleting the bower_components folder. So i guess from here onwards you can customize this script as per your usage.

Comment: This was my original thought, however I need access to the package.json and a variable in it, and I couldn't find a way to do that with `grunt-shell`.

Comment: yes i can see you want to read some file names from `package.json`, so why don't you just mention those things in `Gruntfile.js`? @Seiyria

Comment: I want this to be entirely dynamic so I don't have to add an entry every time I add a new app, @NarendraSoni