# grunt-init-copy grouping subtasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to use grunt copy to do two separate tasks. I don't need to run both sets at the same time, so I'm trying to seperate them. I want to copy all the fonts over, or copy all the global images over. I'm working on a web app for Windows and each page ends up being it's own website with all it's own js, css, etc.

1. Copy all global images into a build folder
2. Copy all global fonts into a build folder

Folder Structure

```
~ Project  
  |-- app  
  |  |-- fonts  
  |  |-- images  
  |  |  |-- global  
  |  |-- php, styles, js, etc  
  |-- build  
  |  |-- page1  
  |  |  |-- fonts  
  |  |  |-- images  
  |  |  |  |-- global
  |  |  |-- html, css, js, etc
```

I was hoping to set up `grunt copy:images` and `grunt copy:fonts` tasks, but so far it's not working as I hoped.

This is a stripped down example of my `Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    copy: {
      images: {
        // copy the global image folder into each build directory
        images1: {
          expand: true,
          src: 'app/img/global/**/*',
          dest: 'build/projectname-1.1-intro/img/global/',
          flatten: true,
          filter: 'isFile',
        },
        // ... there are about 30 more pages in the build to add images to
      },
      fonts: {
        // copy the app/fonts folder into each build directory
        fonts_one: {
          expand: true,
          src: 'app/fonts/**/*',
          dest: 'build/projectname-1.1-intro/fonts/',
          flatten: true,
          filter: 'isFile',
        },
        // ... there are about 30 more pages in the build to add fonts to
      },
    }, // copy
  }); // initConfig
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
} // module.exports
```

And when `grunt copy:images` or `grunt copy:fonts` was run, it returned:

```
Running "copy:images" (copy) task
```

but didn't actually copy anything

The only way I've been able to make it work is to combine all the sub-sub tasks into the task like so:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      copy: {
        // copy the global image folder into each build directory
       images1: {
         expand: true,
         src: 'app/img/global/**/*',
         dest: 'build/projectname-1.1-intro/img/global/',
         flatten: true,
         filter: 'isFile',
       },
       // ... there are about 30 more pages in the build to add images to
       // copy the app/fonts folder into each build directory
       fonts_one: {
         expand: true,
         src: 'app/fonts/**/*',
         dest: 'build/projectname-1.1-intro/fonts/',
         flatten: true,
         filter: 'isFile',
       },
       // ... there are about 30 more pages in the build to add fonts to
     }, // copy
  }); // initConfig
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
} // module.exports
```

Which then returns:

```
Running "copy:images1" (copy) task
Copied 34 files    
Running "copy:fonts_hall1" (copy) task
Copied 34 files
```

I looked into `multitask`, but right now I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The multitasks are how I typically see this being done. That said, you could write a custom task to do this if need be.

Comment: @jakerella Can you recommend any good docs for creating custom tasks? I'll search when I get a chance, but figured I'd ask. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I wrote [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383719/dynamic-grunt-involving-n-subdirectories/21384342#21384342) for a different problem that also uses custom tasks the other day. Maybe look at that? Other than that, I just use the Grunt site ([here](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks) and [there](http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks)).